# Rails: Brakeman gem unprotected mass assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment, brakeman

I am using brakeman gem to find the security issues in my rails application code.

brakeman giving me unprotected mass assigment security issue. below the line that causing this issue.

```
AuthenticationCode.new(:batch_id => batch_id, :code => code_string, :is_active => is_active)
```

But i am not doing any mass assignment here then why brakeman is giving me mass assignment security issue.

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: Could you post the query from the Rails console? Have you set the `strong_parameters` correctly?

Comment: No.. i didn't set strong_parameters. I am not doing mass assignment here then why do i need to set strong_parameters here??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using protected_attributes gem and that's why brakeman was giving me this issue. after removing protected gem attribute it worked.

Thanks,

Sanjay Salunkhe